# How to move Ubuntu partitions?

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu

So this is how my partitions are currently set up:

[image: current setup]

I want to be able to move my main Ubuntu partition left, and move the other ext4 (Files) partition to the right of my root partition (So, windows|root|files|swap) and then merge root and files together. Is there anyway I can do this with minimal risk to trash my entire Ubuntu install?

Another option I was thinking of is installing apps onto the 'files' partition, but from what I've read, it's either very hard, or downright impossible.

Specs:

256 GB SSD
Lubuntu LTS 16.04

Comment: Maybe I'm old, but I feel there is no 'minimal risk' when fiddling with partitions. I don't touch partitions without a fresh complete backup and my handwritten install notes handy.

Comment: hmm. And no way to merge the two partitions as they are right now? I know that moving the partition locations breaks everything (I know from experience).

Comment: The answer below outlines the steps but better to save the personal files to somewhere else like an external drive.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll want to "merge" your "Files" partition with your root partition first. Then move and resize it.

1. Copy your files from the "Files" partition to somewhere on the root partition.
2. Then delete the "Files" partition.
3. Move your root partition to the left.
4. Resize the root partition to take the full available space.

Comment: Doesn't moving the root partition mess up GRUB when booting? Based on that, does GRUB lie in the very beginning of the SSD, causing it to be booted to first (by the bootloader)? Then does GRUB look for bootable partitions?

Comment: Simply moving the root partition should not mess up your grub configuration. GRUB references a particular partition not a sector on the disk. GRUB will make changes to your MBR and store configurations in /boot. In the past there was a requirement that your /boot partition was at the beginning of the disk, but on most modern machines this is not the case.